# Received a job offer email followed by rejection email

Tags: job-offer, recruitment

I received an email from the recruitment manager that my interview was successful however, few days later I received an email from the system that my interview was unsuccessful. I was really happy that I succeeded but I became worried after they sent me a rejection email. I hope it is a mistake. Who shall I ask?

Comment: I disagree with the close. Assuming that you want the job, I would *act* as if you never got the second email, email the recruitment manager and ask about following-up (second interview, offer, when can you start etc.) Worst case scenario, the second email was genuinely, it sucks - keep looking, best case scenario, the second email was in error, you continue the process, Next scenario is that it was a legit email, but because you've followed up, they feel bad and continue the process. Eitherway, you have nothing to loose by acting as if it was never sent.

Comment: There is an existing question almost identical to this one, with an answer people like -- I wrote both, so we'd have it in file. Close as duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

Talk to the recruitment manager. Only they can clear this up for you.